# How to remove the JSON Parameter if a null value is present in CSV file for the Parameter in the JSON object in Rest API Testing

Tags: json, rest, jmeter

I have a PUT API, Which will update the contact data based on the UserID (User ID is mandatory and my JSON object looks as below.

```
{ 
      "userId": "test",
      "firstName": "Test",
      "lastName": "TG",
      "countryCode": "1",
      "phone": "112-123-234"
   }
```

I have Used CSV Data Config to pass the Parameter values and My data looks like below

[image]

So in this case if the Firstname value is null in CSV the JSON object is being passed as

```
{ 
      "userId": "test2",
      "firstName": "",
      "lastName": "TG",
      "countryCode": "1",
      "phone": "112-123-234"
   }
```

Instead I wanted it to be passed as (It should not contain the First name parameter itself)

```
{ 
      "userId": "test2",
      "lastName": "TG",
      "countryCode": "1",
      "phone": "112-123-234"
    }
```

Is there a way to do this? Using JMeter

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no built-in way to do it. However it can be worked around using [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor)

1. Given your CSV Data Set Config variables look like:

   ```
   userId,firstName,lastName,countryCode,phone
   ```
2. Add Beanshell PreProcessor **as a child** of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) Sampler
3. Put the following code into the Beanshell PreProcessor "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPArgument;

   String[] parameters = new String[]{vars.get("userId"), vars.get("firstName"), vars.get("lastName"), vars.get("countryCode"), vars.get("phone")};
   StringBuilder requestBody = new StringBuilder();
   String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
   String tab = "\t";
   requestBody.append("{");
   requestBody.append(newLine);
   for (String value : parameters) {
       String key = "";
       if (value.length() > 0) {
           for (Map.Entry entry : vars.entrySet()) {
               if (Objects.equals(value, entry.getValue())) {
                   key = entry.getKey().toString();
               }
           }
           requestBody.append(tab).append("\"").append(key).append("\": \"").append(value).append("\"");
           requestBody.append(newLine);
       }
   }

   requestBody.append("}");
   HTTPArgument arg = new HTTPArgument();
   arg.setValue(requestBody.toString());
   Arguments args = new Arguments();
   args.addArgument(arg);
   sampler.setArguments(args);
   ```

Above code will add JSON argument only if value is present.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on using JMeter and Java API from Beanshell test elements.

Comment: Hi, I really like this solution, and I would thank you for sharing this. However I found an issue: if there are two columns with the same value, only the last one will be added in the request, or sometimes, the first value is added twice. how could it be fixed?

Answer (score -1):

you can parameterize userid by using CSV Dataset config,
refer https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG